# How can I posts parameter to an ajax request?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a Google request to determine is a name already taken or not as a gmail name. Here is my code:

```
$data = [];
$data = ['input01' =>
                ['Input'=>'GmailAddress',
                  'GmailAddress' => 'myEmailName',
                  'FirstName' => '',
                  'LastName' => '',
                ],
         'Locale' => 'en'
        ];

$url = "https://accounts.google.com/InputValidator?resource=SignUp&service=mail";
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));// here we are passing $data
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$res = curl_exec($handle);

echo $res;
```

I've found that url from [this page](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ltmpl=default). But the result of my code is:

> ### Bad Request
>
> Error 400

How can I do that?

Comment: I think, Google also looking for some cookies. you can use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-inspector/jgbbilmfbammlbbhmmgaagdkbkepnijn?hl=en) extension on chrome to look into cookies set by google on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass header type as json to inform server that request params are in json

```
$data = [];
$data = ['input01' =>
                ['Input'=>'GmailAddress',
                  'GmailAddress' => 'myEmailName',
                  'FirstName' => '',
                  'LastName' => '',
                ],
         'Locale' => 'en'
        ];

$url = "https://accounts.google.com/InputValidator?resource=SignUp&service=mail";
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));// here we are passing $data

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); //<----- Add this line
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$res = curl_exec($handle);

echo $res;
```

Comment: Yes it works .. but I don't see the different between your code and my code. What did you change?